# what does $p(-1) = 0$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

In a linear algebra problem, it asks me to determine the subespace spanned by
$$
\left\{ p(x)  \in \mathbb{R}^3 : p(-1) = 0 \right\}.
$$
What does it mean?

Comment: is there a function p(x) defined anywhere else in the question?

Comment: Are you sure it has $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: The OP said R3, I hope I did not misinterpret it.

Answer (score 1):

$p(x)$ is a polynom with real valued coefficients. It means that $-1$ is a root of $p(x)$.

You have to find the vector subspace formed by all the polynoms on $\mathbb{R}[x]$, with the restriction that $-1$ must be a root of those polynoms.

Comment: How to understand the cube ?

Comment: I think it's a mistake. I found that this cube has no sense. $R[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, it has more sense $\mathbb{R}[x]$ than $\mathbb{R^3}$.